# Can not save/restore subset of variables in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am training my network with ImageNet so I can use a subset of the trained weights for my project.

Saving and restoring the hole weights is not a problem but when I try to save them without the fully connected layers it gives me an error: **NameError: global name 'w1' is not defined**. If it helps anyone, the repository is in [github](https://github.com/tnikolla/grasp-detection/blob/master/grasp.py) or a snippet of code:

**inference.py**

```
...
def inference(images):
    w1 = tf.get_variable('w1', shape=[5,5,3,64])   
    ...
```

**grasp.py**

```
def run_training():
  ...
  logits = inference(images)
  ...
init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)
saver = tf.train.Saver({'w1': w1})
```

The *Traceback*:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./grasp.py", line 130, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-
    packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "./grasp.py", line 83, in main
    run_training()
  File "./grasp.py", line 52, in run_training
    saver = tf.train.Saver({'w1': w1})
NameError: global name 'w1' is not defined
```

If you have any suggestions or you need more info, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to access the variable from the `tf.global_variables()` set.

```
w1 = [v for v in tf.global_variables() if v.name == 'w1:0'][0]
saver = tf.train.Saver({'w1': w1})
```

Comment: I found this one too, `w1 = [v for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES) if v.name == 'w1:0'][0]`.